# reactjs get `undefined is not a function` on testing with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I have a React components. I want to test them. But I get unexpected error on every trying to `findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag` with tested component. Here is the Karma error log:

```
05 09 2015 20:31:23.450:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/tmp/35ffb917aab483a567d1be6fed779291.browserify".
PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0) DestroySession should process user logout FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'target.dispatchEvent(e)') in http://localhost:9876/karma.js (line 1134)
        at /tmp/35ffb917aab483a567d1be6fed779291.browserify:59730:16
PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 7 (1 FAILED) (skipped 4) (0.04 secs / 0.019 secs)
```

My stack is:

- coffeescript
- react(+jsx)
- browserify
- karma.js
- phantomjs
- jasmine

Component:

```
React = require('react')
ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap')

Button = ReactBootstrap.Button

SessionActions = require('../../actions/session_actions.coffee')

module.exports = React.createClass
  contextTypes: router: React.PropTypes.func
  handleClick: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log 'хуйло'
    SessionActions.destroy()
    @context.router.transitionTo('/sessions/new')
  render: ->
    <Button onClick={@handleClick} className='btn btn-default navbar-btn'>Sign out</Button>
```

Test:

```
React = require('react/react-with-addons.js')
TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils

DestroySession = require('../../../../app/coffee/components/sessions/destroy.coffee')

describe 'DestroySession', ->
  instance = undefined

  beforeEach ->
    instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<DestroySession />)


  it 'should process user logout', ->
    localStorage.setItem('token', 123)
    localStorage.setItem('userName', 'Anonymous Person')
    localStorage.setItem('userId', 11)

    button = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(instance, 'button')

    console.log button
```

It's very strange, but I get an error when I try to `console.log` my button variable. If I comment out last line of my test, it will be passed. What's happened?

Comment: I see this as well: I can evaluate and test against the instance successfully, but if I push the instance to `console.log`, I get the same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `getDOMNode()`

`console.log button.getDOMNode()`

**Note**: This is changing in 0.14.2 where TestUtils.find/scry methods will return the DOM node directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the right answer, but I landed here because I got the exact same exception in Jasmine, and I uncovered what caused it, so I'll leave this here:

The mistake I made was to accidentally save the global **document** inside an object, instead of a local variable called **document**:

```
/*
var document = {
   parentId: parentItem._id, 
   childIds: [childItem._id],
};
I had moved the above elsewhere, so "document" now refers to window.document
*/
db.saveInIndex(parentId, document);
```

And later made a call to this:

```
console.log(db.getFromIndex(parentId));
```

Which resulted in this:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'target.dispatchEvent(e)')
```

Because it was trying to log an object that looked like this:

```
{
  parentId: 'HA89A8S98A98',
  document: <<< the global "document" - not what we wanted! >>>
}
```

That global var **document** would normally be the HTML contents of your page, but when you're running your tests against PhantomJS you get it's own interpretation of that!

(running Karma against Chrome gave a different exception)